# I want to automate the cucumber steps using ruby class

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Login.feature

```
Background:
      Given I am on Google

    Scenario: Search for a term
      When I fill in "q" found by "name" with "TestingBot"
      And I submit
      Then I should see title "TestingBot - Google Search"
```

Here i added some sample cucumber steps. File name is login.feature. I want to create the automation ruby script for above steps.

Give the folder structure in eclipse.

Comment: What is your specific question?  You want to create the step definitons?

Comment: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2009/10/03/getting-started-with-cucumber-rspec-webrat-and-multiruby/ and https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse - you didn't put much effort into the question, maybe you can work on the answer.

Comment: @orde My question describes i need to implement the cucumber step definitions into ruby class for automation.

Answer (score 1):

Sample folder structure for a cucumber project:

> - cucumber
>
>   - features
>   - step_definitions
>   - support